# Passing a C# Dictionary as a function parameter to allocate its memory does not work

Tags: c#, dictionary, object, collections, ref

I have  below code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
class Program {
    static void add(Dictionary<string,string> hello){
      hello = new Dictionary<string,string>();
      hello["hello"] = "hello";
    }
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      Employee employee = new Employee(); // Employee class
      
      add(employee.hello);     //  employee.hello is property like public Dictionary<string,string> hello {get;set;}
        Console.WriteLine(hello["hello"]);
    }
}
```

I have also tried using `ref` but i'm getting `A property or indexer may not be passed as ref`

When I intialize `hello` this program  works fine but when i try to intialize it in function it is giving me null reference error. So is there any way to initialize dictionary by passing through a function like that ?

Comment: You need [`ref`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref)

Comment: I have tried that it is giving me an error "A Property or indexer must not be passed by reference"

Comment: Adding `ref` worked in my test using your code. Can you show the code that causes the error?

Comment: I have updated my code

Comment: It's invalid, you didn't declare variable `hello` in `Main`.

Comment: Posting real code is invaluable in use providing you help.

Comment: A property is a pair of methods. You can't pass a pair of methods as an argument where a variable is expected. If you will *always* create a new dictionary, don't bother with an argument, just return it.

Comment: *"you're mixing up the responsibilities of your classes and methods.

The class Employee should be responsible for setting up its own fields."* -- Enigmativity

Comment: Don't use an automatic property for the `Employee` property, use an old-fashion one with a backing field. Pass the field in by ref

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered passing in the Employee object instead of one of its properties? Something like...

```
static void add(Employee emp) {
  emp.hello = new Dictionary<string, string>();
  emp.hello["hello"] = "hello";
}


static void Main(string[] args) {
  Employee employee = new Employee(); // Employee class
  add(employee);
  Console.WriteLine(employee.hello["hello"]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to chose if you are passing in a created dictionary or creating one in the `add` method.

Here's option 1:

```
class Program
{
    static void add(Dictionary<string, string> hello)
    {
        hello["hello"] = "hello";
    }
    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        add(employee.hello);
        Console.WriteLine(employee.hello["hello"]);
    }
}

public class Employee
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> hello = new Dictionary<string, string>();
}
```

Here's option 2:

```
class Program
{
    static Dictionary<string, string> add() =>
        new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            { "hello", "hello" },
        };
    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.hello = add();
        Console.WriteLine(employee.hello["hello"]);
    }
}

public class Employee
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> hello = null;
}
```

And, option 3, also works.

```
class Program
{
    static void add(ref Dictionary<string, string> hello)
    {
        if (hello == null)
        {
            hello = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        }
        hello["hello"] = "hello";
    }
    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        add(ref employee.hello);
        Console.WriteLine(employee.hello["hello"]);
    }
}

public class Employee
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> hello = null;
}
```

All three of those print `hello` to the console.

It's a little unclear what you're trying to do. But if it is the last one then you're mixing up the responsibilities of your classes and methods.

The class `Employee` should be responsible for setting up its own fields.

Finally, it would be useful for you to use the C# variable and method naming standards.